# amazon.fr hints that the Boost app will be available on phones?

Tags: software, boost

At this moment (end of the year, 2017), the description for Lego Boost on the french amazon site [includes the notice](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226004141/https://www.amazon.fr/LEGO-17101-Premi%C3%A8res-Constructions-Boost/dp/B06X6GN2VQ/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1514248378&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=lego%20boost&psc=1):

> Enfin, l'application sera également disponible sur smartphones dès les
>   vacances de fin d'année.

(translates to: Finally [it's after the list of compatible tablet Os'],  the application will also be available on smartphones from the end of the year vacation.)

Has anyone read anything about this elsewhere? I'm failing to find anything on google, the LEGO site or the German or UK Amazon sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V1.4.4 on [Apple App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lego-boost/id1217385613?mt=8) state “support for mobile phones”, and it does install fine on iPhones. Finally.

[image]

V1.4.3 on the [Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.boost.boost) also lists "support for mobile phones" in the "What's New" section and can be installed on my Samsung S7.

Comment: The version on the Amazon app store also installs on phones. I've installed it and started it up but I don't have the Boost kit to test.

Answer (score 2):

Installs and seems to run on my smartphone (galaxy A5), but haven't opened my boost set yet to verify further. I think lego indeed recently started supporting smartphones.